# Convert json response to C# variables

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint, console-application

How do I convert returned JSON values into variables in my console application? I get  a JSON response of multiple companies (750+) from a rest api call and write it to the console app, which looks like this:

```
"companies": [
    {
        "guid": "81eb95d6-d89e-4e93-aad0-eff89a450fcf",
        "name": "Example Company 1",
        "rating": 770,
        "rating_date": "2018-05-27"
          },
    {
        "guid": "81eb95d6-d89e-4e93-aad0-eff89a450fcf",
        "name": "Example Company 2",
        "rating": 810,
        "rating_date": "2018-05-27"
    },
    {
        "guid": "81eb95d6-d89e-4e93-aad0-eff89a450fcf",
        "name": "Example Company 3",          
        "rating": 760,
        "rating_date": "2018-05-27"
    },`
```

Using SharePoint client I am then looking to upload these company values as items in a sharepoint list.

```
    {
        ClientContext context = new  ClientContext("http://exampleSharepoint/List");

        List companiesList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Companies");

        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem newItem = companiesList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        newItem["Title"] = CompanyTitle;
        newItem["guid"] = Guid;
        newItem["Rating"] = Rating;
        newItem["Rating Date"] = RatingDate;
        newItem.Update();

        context.ExecuteQuery();

    }
```

I have had a look at json deserializer but have hard time applying it to my context. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Evere worked with Newtonsoft json serializer? I believe that would answer your question.

You're looking for this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/
An example use case here would be `var companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Company>>(jsonString);`

Granted you would have a model to deserialize this into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to convert the json into an object which you can then use in the code explicitly?

You need to get the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package first.

You can use the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() method to deserialize the json string to a c# object.

All you need is the corresponding c# object that matches the json. In your case you need something like:

```
public class Company
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "guid")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rating")]
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rating_date")]
    public DateTime Rating_date { get; set; }
 }
```

You can deserialize to a list of this object straight from your Json:

```
List<Company> companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(JsonString);
```